# Eigenvectors Trajectories

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, control-theory

I got stuck with a problem while studying for a control systems exam. It goes as following:

"Look at the picture of trajectories of a linear, time-invariant system with the form:
$\frac{d\mathbf{x}}{dt}=\mathbf{A}x$.

The Eigenvalues of the matrix $A$ are $s_1=-1$ and $s_2=-2$.

Find the Eigenvectors $p_1$ and $p_2$ considering the given Eigenvalues."

How can I calculate the Eigenvectors with just knowing the Eigenvalues and the trajectories?

Thanks in advance

[image: trajectories]

Comment: Hint: look ar trajectories that are straight  lines.

Comment: Okay, so is it then just about finding two vectors which point to somewhere on the straight trajectories?
Like $\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

The general solution is 
$$
x(t) = c_1 \xi_1 e^{\lambda_1 t} + c_2 \xi_2 e^{\lambda_2 t},
$$
where $\xi_j$ are the eigenvectors, and $\lambda_j$ are the eigenvalues.

If the coefficients (or initial condition) are chosen so $c_1 = 1$ and $c_2 = 0$ then the solution is

$$
x(t) = \xi_1 e^{\lambda_1 t}.
$$

If $\xi_1 = \begin{pmatrix}a \\ b\end{pmatrix}$, then this solution can be written
$$
\begin{pmatrix}x_1(t) \\ x_2(t) \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}a e^{\lambda_1 t} \\ b e^{\lambda_1 t}\end{pmatrix}
$$

and in particular, for all $t$, $x_1$ and $x_2$ satisfy

$$
x_2 = b e^{\lambda_1 t} = b\left(\dfrac{1}{a} x_1\right) = \dfrac{b}{a}x_1
$$

i.e. the entire solution lies in the line passing through the origin, with slope $\dfrac{b}{a}$.