# Prove that trajectory that starts in span of eigenvector will remain there

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Assume we have a 2-d system of homogeneous ordinary differential equations:$$
\dot{\mathbf{x}}=\left[
  \begin{array}{ c c }
     a & b \\
     c & d
  \end{array} \right]\mathbf{x}=A\mathbf{x}
$$
and the solution is a case of nonrepeating real eigenvalues. Is there a simple proof that if the initial condition is a multiple of $\mathbf{v_i}$, then the trajectory must remain within the span of $\mathbf{v_i}$?

More specifically, the general solution for such a system is:
$$
\mathbf{x}=a_1 \mathbf{v_1}e^{\lambda_1 t}+a_2 \mathbf{v_2}e^{\lambda_2 t}
$$
where $\lambda_i$ and $\mathbf{v_i}$ are eigenvalue/eigenvector pairs. Is there a simple proof that if $\mathbf{x_0}\in span(\mathbf{v_i})$, then the trajectory will remain in $span(\mathbf{v_i})$?

**My attempt**
Let $\mathbf{x_0}=\alpha\mathbf{v_1}$, and let $\Delta t$ be very small:
$$
\mathbf{x}(\Delta t)=\mathbf{x_0}+\Delta t(A\mathbf{x_0})=\mathbf{x_0}+\Delta t(\alpha A \mathbf{v_1})=\alpha \mathbf{v_1}+(\Delta t \alpha \lambda_1) \mathbf{v_1} \in span(\mathbf{v_1})
$$
If this is true for a very small $\Delta t$, then it can be iterated each step along the trajectory. Unfortunately, my attempt is not very good, as it basically amounts to looking at what would happen if you employed Euler approximation to the solution. My hunch is I am missing a much more elegant, analytical solution.

Related post:
[Eigenvectors Trajectories](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/654979/eigenvectors-trajectories)

Note this is for self-study, as I prepare to present some basic differential equations to a science (not math) audience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though the answer by @user44197 is absolutely correct, here is slight rephrase of it. You are given that the solution starts, e.g., in $\text{Span}\,v_1$. This means that the initial condition is $x_0=\alpha v_1$ for some $\alpha\in \mathbb R$. Now consider the function
$$
x(t)=\alpha v_1 e^{\lambda_1 t}.
$$
This function satisfies $x(0)=x_0$, and it also solves the equation since
$$
x'(t)=\alpha v_1 \lambda_1 e^{\lambda_1 t}=Ax(t)=A\alpha v_1e^{\lambda_1 t}=\alpha v_1\lambda_1 e^{\lambda_1 t}.
$$
Due to the existence and uniqueness theorem this is the only solution that starts in span of $v_1$ and by its form (for any $t$ it has the form $\beta v_1$) it is in the span of $v_1$. Q.E.D.

Comment: This is a nice simple one like I was hoping for, thanks! I like that it requires no additional linear algebra than the definition of an eigenvector (which they already know), and relies more on intuitions about differential equations instead (the Existence and Uniqueness Theorem).

Answer (score 2):

From your general solution, at $t=0$ you have 
$$
x(0)=a_1 v_1 + a_2 v_2
$$

Now if $x(0)$ is in the span of $v_1$ then $a_2=0$ and
$$
x(t) = \left(a_1 e^{\lambda_1 t} \right) v_1
$$
Hence the result

**Post script**
You can generalize this to any number of eigenvectors as long as eigenvectors span the space:

If at any time $x(t)$ has no component along $v_k$ then $x(t)$ will never have a component along $v_k$ where the component is calculated by writing $x$ as a linear combination of eigenvectors.

**Additional comments**
If $v_1$ and $v_2$ are linearly independent, and $\alpha_1 v_1 + \alpha_2 v_2$ is one way to express a vector as linear combination, then **it is the only way** to express the vector as linear combination of $v_1$ and $v_2$.

Comment: "Now if x(0) is in the span of v1 then a2=0." This seems to just give another way to re-express my original question. That is, how can one prove that if $x_0=\alpha v_1$ then $a_2=0$, in a simple way? This is equivalent to my question (indeed, originally I had it worded your way too, and had a discussion of the post I linked to (which makes the same point) but I cut all this for space).

Comment: By definition of linear independence.

Comment: Are you saying we could use linear independence of the evectors, and the fact that each point in $\mathbb{R}^2$ has a unique representation under their basis, to show that once we have found **one** solution ($a_1=\alpha, a_2=0$), we know there is no other solution? This seems promising, but I was frankly hoping for a more simple intuitive proof that I might use for those that haven't had linear algebra course yet (e.g., a geometric proof in 2d). [Edit: just noticed your additional comments above on your answer, so this is indeed the path you were thinking...].